# Will Ito's Isometry result in $E\left(\int_0^t \cos(u)\,dB_u \int_0^t \sin(u)\, dB_u \right) = E\left(\int_0^t \cos(u) \sin(u)\, du \right)$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

If I have two integrals, $X_t = \int_0^t \cos(u)\,dB_u$and $Y_t  = \int_0^t \sin(u)\, dB_u$ , where $B_u$ is a Wiener Process and I am trying to find:

$$
E\left(\int_0^t \cos(u)\,dB_u \int_0^t \sin(u)\, dB_u \right)
$$

I am wondering if I can apply Ito's Isometry to obtain the relation:
$$
E\left(\int_0^t \cos(u)\,dB_u \int_0^t \sin(u)\, dB_u \right) = E\left(\int_0^t \cos(u) \sin(u)\, du \right)
$$

I know that this relation is true but don't know how to get it. Thanks!

Comment: Is $B_u$ the same Wiener process?

Comment: Yes, just added it, thanks!

Comment: Then yes, the last equation is true, an it is called Itô's isometry. But you say you already know that. You need a proof?

Comment: It is my impression that for Ito's Isometry to work, the integrand has to be the same. However, the integrand above is of different form, namely $cos(u)$ and $sin(u)$. At least that is my impression from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry. Am I failing to understand a nuanced part about the isometry? Thanks!

Comment: @Siron has given you the answer below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Apply the polarization identity in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$xy = \frac{1}{4}((x+y)^2-(x-y)^2),$$
to $x = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{t} \cos(u) dB_u$ and $y = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{t} \sin(u) dB_u$, together with the Itô-isometry. This will lead to the result.